# Android layout NavigationRailView items cut of in small ViewPort

Tags: android, layout

I'm using the `com.google.android.material.navigationrail.NavigationRailView` with 5 Nav items.
With most phones, it just works perfectly. I see all 5 nav items including subtitles on my screen's (left) side.
The problem is phones with small ViewPorts: 
The last icon with text is then cut off, and the user can't see the whole icon and the text isn't visible.
[image] 
This is my layout:

```
        <com.google.android.material.navigationrail.NavigationRailView
            android:id="@+id/rail_navigation"
            style="@style/MyApp.Widget.RailNavigationView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="false"
            android:visibility="visible"
            app:menuGravity="top"
            tools:menu="@menu/menu_fragment_top_app_bar" />
```

I tried to add `app:itemVerticalPadding="1dp"` but that didn't change anything.